# What is the most efficient way to represent an directed dynamic massive 3D graph?

Tags: graphs, data-structures, simulation

I know that there are [many techniques to represent graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33592816/159072).

Suppose I have a directed massive 3D graph with 100,000 nodes at maximum.

Suppose the graph looks somewhat like the following:

[image]

Suppose each node of the graph has three pieces of information:

1. A 30-character string as a label
2. floating point values as coordinates
3. three integer values

The graph is dynamic. I.e., connections frequently change, and the nodes frequently change their coordinates.

What would be the most efficient way to represent this graph in computer memory so that I can apply mathematical operations on each node?

Should I use data structures, or should I use big-data techniques?

Comment: A graph is an abstract data structure, it does not have a spatial extent (saying 3D is irrelevant). A key parameter to choose the representation is the number of edges. And it also matters to know which queries you need to perform on the graph.

Answer (score 1):

50,000 nodes is very small and will fit in memory.  Use any standard data structure for representing graphs, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).

Comment: But, each node contains some data...

Comment: @user366312: in what way would this make a problem ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, where do I store these extra values if I use an Adjacency list or matrix?

Comment: @user366312: elsewhere.